# Creating new async tasks

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, rx-java

In the past, I have used AsyncTasks to perform network requests for my Android app. I recently switched to RxJava to be able to cancel the requests when the user exits an activity. I have created a system to easily create new async tasks via RxJava which all cancel when a user exits an activity. I have attached some basic code that I hope somebody could give me some pointers on.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ArrayList<OnDestroyListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        for(OnDestroyListener listener : listeners){
            listener.onDestroy();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void addOnDestroyListener(OnDestroyListener listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public interface OnDestroyListener{
        void onDestroy();
    }
}

public class Tools{
    public static <E> void observe(Callable<E> callable, SingleSubscriber<E> subscriber, BaseActivity activity){
        final Subscription sub = Single.fromCallable(callable)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(subscriber);

        if(activity == null){
            return;
        }

        activity.addOnDestroyListener(new BaseActivity.OnDestroyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                sub.unsubscribe();
            }
        });
    }
}

public class Endpoint{
    public void makeGetRequestAsync(final String url, final SingleSubscriber<String> subscriber, BaseActivity activity){
        Tools.observe(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                return makeGetRequestSync(url);
            }
        }, subscriber, activity);
    }
}

public class SampleActivity extends BaseActivity{

    Endpoint endpoint = new Endpoint();

    void onButtonClick(View v){ 
        endpoint.makeGetRequestAsync("https://someurl.com", new SingleSubscriber<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String result) {
                        //Request success
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable error) {
                        //Request failure
                    }
                }, this);
    }
}
```

I know that I do not have a real coding problem, since this method has been working very well so far, but I just want to know if anything about this process is inherently wrong, as I am using it throughout my app.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by trying to make a separate package for making the requests, something like a presenter(MVP pattern - [MVP in Android](https://www.google.de/search?q=MVP%20pattern%20android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=xv10WLuZLtOo8wfsmYnwBQ)). 
Because, the way you have it now, it is hard to be tested and inside of the activity you have more logic, breaking a bit the SRP principle( [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) ).

Now, all it is left to do is to connect the activity and the presenter and that you can do using a callback. 
 
Also, as a bonus, all the stuff you need, presenter, etc, you can add to a dagger module.